# A question about 目を合わせる

Tags: grammar, verbs, expressions, て-form, tense

So the thing is that I found the next sentence:

> 目を合わせて逸らさない、というのはそれだけで真摯に見える。

I understand the whole sentence and all, but that 「目を合わせて逸らさない」is troubling me.

I asked what it meant, and it was something like "To make eye contact and not look away", but then, does the tense of the last verb not affect the former one?

Maybe is it some kind of expression?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is troubling you about the tenses? It's not clear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if the negative form of the verb 逸らす would also affect 合わせる, it would not. "To make eye contact and not look away" is correct. If you want both to be negative, you would have to say "合わせないで逸らさない" (although, it makes no sense in this context).